# Create PDF with array of values belonging to collectionproxy using Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4

Creating a PDF with questions and answers. The questions are created fine. Now I am trying to put the related answers next to or below each question.

I am able to show one answer per question, now I am having a problem because the answers are stored in an Array.

The controller:

```
def show
  @all_answers = []
  @test = Test.find(params[:id])
  @test_questions = @test.questions
  @test_questions.each do |a|
    @all_answers << Answer.find_all_by_question_id(a)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      pdf = TestReport.new(@test_questions, @all_answers)
      send_data pdf.render, filename: 'certification_test.pdf', type: 'application/pdf' , disposition: 'inline' 
    end
  end
end
```

PDF class code:

```
class TestReport < LayoutPdf

def initialize(test=[], answer=[])
  super()
  @test_questions = test
  @all_answers = answer

  header 'Certification Test'
  display_test
  footer

end

def display_test
  table test_questions do
    self.header = true
    self.column_widths = [40, 300, 200]
  end  
end

def test_questions
  [['#', 'Question']] +
  @test_me ||= @test_questions.map { |e| [e.id, e.content] } +
  #@all_answers.each do |a| a.content end
  @answer_me ||= @all_answers.map { |a| [a.content] }
end
end
```

@all_answers is an array like this:

```
[[#<Answer id: 1, content: "It walked", question_id: 1, correct: false, created_at: "x", updated_at: "x">, #<Answer id: 2, content: "It was thrown", question_id: 1, correct: true, created_at: "x", updated_at: "x">, #<Answer id: 3, content: "It got run over and pushed", question_id: 1, correct: false, created_at: "x", updated_at: "x">], [#<Answer id: 4, content: "False", question_id: 2, correct: true, created_at: "x", updated_at: "x">, #<Answer id: 5, content: "True", question_id: 2, correct: false, created_at: "x", updated_at: "x">]]
```

The error I get for this line: `@answer_me ||= @all_answers.map { |a| a.content }`

```
undefined method `content' for #<Array:0x007f2cbac9e620>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@all_answers` is an array of arrays. You should flatten it before iterating over it:

```
@answer_me ||= @all_answers.flatten.map { |a| a.content }
```

Comment: Oh, an array of arrays. :/