# Join array and hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

Ruby on Rails 4

I am trying to join an Array of questions and a grouped by hash together by the question's id.

The Hash is grouped by the question_id attribute of its records from Answers.

The Array has all the Questions, and index is id.

I was trying to put them into an array, @pdf. The question first then the answers by the enumerator index. But it is behaving odd.

```
@pdf = []
@test = Test.find(params[:id])
@test_questions = @test.questions
answers = Answer.find(:all)
@all_answers = answers.group_by(&:question_id)
@test_questions.each do |q|
  @pdf << q
  @pdf << @all_answers.select { |i| i == q }
end
```

The log shows this:

```
=> [#<Question id: 1, content: "How did the chicken cross the road?", question_type: "MC", category: "ip_voice", product_id: 8, active: true, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", user_id: 1>, {}, #<Question id: 2, content: "Is this working?", question_type: "TF", category: "ip_voice", product_id: 6, active: true, created_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", updated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", user_id: 1>, {}]
```

This is @all_answers:

```
=> {1=>[#<Answer id: 1, content: "It walked", question_id: 1, correct: false, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14">, #<Answer id: 2, content: "It was thrown", question_id: 1, correct: true, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14">, #<Answer id: 3, content: "It got run over and pushed", question_id: 1, correct: false, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14">], 2=>[#<Answer id: 4, content: "False", question_id: 2, correct: true, created_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", updated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53">, #<Answer id: 5, content: "True", question_id: 2, correct: false, created_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", updated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53">]}
```

This is @test_questions:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Question id: 1, content: "How did the chicken cross the road?", question_type: "MC", category: "ip_voice", product_id: 8, active: true, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", user_id: 1>, #<Question id: 2, content: "Is this working?", question_type: "TF", category: "ip_voice", product_id: 6, active: true, created_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", updated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", user_id: 1>]>
```

I am new to many Rails/Ruby methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create PDF with array of values belonging to collectionproxy using Prawn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768731/create-pdf-with-array-of-values-belonging-to-collectionproxy-using-prawn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the code you need:

```
@pdf = []
@test = Test.find(params[:id])
@test_questions = @test.questions
answers = Answer.find(:all)
@all_answers = answers.group_by(&:question_id)
@test_questions.each do |q|
  @pdf << q
  @pdf += @all_answers[q.id]
end
```

This should create something like:

```
=> [#<Question id: 1, content: "How did the chicken cross the road?", question_type: "MC", category: "ip_voice", product_id: 8, active: true, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", user_id: 1>, #<Answer id: 1, content: "It walked", question_id: 1, correct: false, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14">, #<Answer id: 2, content: "It was thrown", question_id: 1, correct: true, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14">, #<Answer id: 3, content: "It got run over and pushed", question_id: 1, correct: false, created_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14", updated_at: "2014-05-07 17:10:14">, 
    #<Question id: 2, content: "Is this working?", question_type: "TF", category: "ip_voice", product_id: 6, active: true, created_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", updated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", user_id: 1>, #<Answer id: 4, content: "False", question_id: 2, correct: true, created_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", updated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53">, #<Answer id: 5, content: "True", question_id: 2, correct: false, created_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53", updated_at: "2014-05-13 16:10:53">]
```

Comment: I get, TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into Array

Comment: In what line? What is the value of `@all_answers[q.id]`?

Comment: +1 Nevermind, the error was my spelling. I am getting this error though, Prawn::Errors::UnrecognizedTableContent but it is in my other class. I'm working on it.

Comment: Worked great! The array was neatly organized with the question, then all the answers.

Comment: I think he should be doing an `ActiveRecord#joins` that's a cleaner way to approach this problem that using ruby Enumerables

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is to have something like this:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, :through => :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

And then do:

```
test = Test.find(params[:id]).joins(:questions, :answers)
```

This will fetch questions and answers in one query and you can do things like:

```
test.questions.first.answers
```

or

```
test.answers
```

and for the pdf:

```
test.questions.each do |q|
pdf = test.questions.collect do |q|
  [q, q.answers]
end
```

Comment: I don't think this would allow a question to belong to many tests. I have a join table, question_tests that stores the Question ids for a Test. Answer belongs to a question.